# Center div, but for smaller sizes use left

Tags: css

So my layout looks like this:

- Left bar, `width: 200px; left: 0;`
- Center, `width: 700px; left: 250px;`
- Right, `width: 200px; right: 10px;`

This works, but for bigger screen sizes, I want Center to be, well, centered.  Regardless of size, though, I always want **at least** `left: 250px`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It seems you're using `absolute` or `relative` positioning in order to position the columns, if so that's really a bad idea since it depends on the size of viewport. You could use CSS floats to position the left/right columns and use a proper margin on the center one: http://jsbin.com/eviqet/7/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS media queries to achieve this:

```
@media screen and(min-width: 1001px){
    .center{
        margin: auto;
    }
}

@media screen and(max-width: 1000px){
    .center{
        left: 250px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a link to mozilla's developer page on CSS media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 2):

CSS Media Queries as Marcel presented are probably the best solution. For future reference, generally responsive web development demands the use of %'s rather than pixels to adjust to screen size variance.

approximately -->

```
Left { width: 17%; left: 0; min-width: 250px; /*margin-right: 50px;*/ }
Center { width: 65%; left: 20%; position: absolute; }
Right { width: 17%; right: 10px; }
```

Comment: While this is OK, I want `left` to always be 250+ pixels.  Screens with width under 1250 will not have that with this method.

Comment: @DavidStarkey  how's that? better? set min-width to 250px instead of 200.

Comment: Better.  Ended up using Marcel's since it's something I've never seen before and I wanted to learn about it.

Comment: definitely CSS3 is the way to go. glad you found a solution :)